# How to rewrite a c++ function from an R package

Tags: r, rcpp

I am using the compute_iterative_ratings function from the R package "comperank":
https://github.com/cran/comperank/blob/master/src/RcppExports.cpp

I would like to modify this function so that it accepts one more argument (an integer variable called **amateur**), so that the function becomes:

*compute_iterative_ratings(rate_fun, player1_id, score1, player2_id, score2, initial_ratings, **amateur**)*

I'd like to just copy the cpp file, modify it to accept the extra argument, and then save it into my working directory so that I can then call sourceCpp for when I need it. This is all new territory for me so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to edit. I also do not know what the final 2 blocks of code mean.

```
static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
    {"_comperank_compute_iterative_ratings", (DL_FUNC) &_comperank_compute_iterative_ratings, 6},
    {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

RcppExport void R_init_comperank(DllInfo *dll) {
    R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
    R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you are looking at is autogenerated. This code will be updated when you adjust the corresponding C++ function and call `Rcpp::compileAttributes` within the package. So instead of RcppExports.cpp you should edit [iterative-ratings.cpp](https://github.com/cran/comperank/blob/master/src/iterative-ratings.cpp). This is also true when using `Rcpp::sourceCpp`.

Answer (score 0):

The only part there you'll need to change is the number `6` to `7`, as it informs R about the number of parameters in the function `_comperank_compute_iterative_ratings`.

```
static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
    {"_comperank_compute_iterative_ratings", (DL_FUNC) &_comperank_compute_iterative_ratings, 7},
    {NULL, NULL, 0}
};
```

For more information see
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Registering-native-routines

Comment: Well that code is autogenerated for you if you use Rcpp as indented.